# How do I compute this improper integral?

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

$$\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{1}{2x^2-x}dx$$

This is a Type II improper integral because the function is undefined at $x=\frac{1}{2}$.
If I were to do this problem on my own I would split this integral in two,

$$\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}}\dfrac{1}{2x^2-x}dx+\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{1}\dfrac{1}{2x^2-x}dx$$

now I have two more improper integrals. I am unsure how to split these two integrals further so I would be able to compute them. Could someone offer me a hint?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\frac1{2x^2-x}=\frac2{2x-1}-\frac1x$$

**Added:** If you’re asking about splitting one of the two integrals into two, to get three integrals altogether, note that the original integral is improper at $0$ as well as at $\frac12$: you need to break it in two so as to get integrals that are improper at only one endpoint.

Comment: I checked the solution manual and they split the improper integrals into 3 separate integrals. From $0$ to $0.4$, $0.4$ to $1/2$, and from $1/2$ to $1$. I cannot figure out why they chose $0.4$. Do you know what they did to get $0.4$?

Comment: @Steven: They needed to split the integral from $0$ to $\frac12$ somewhere, because it’s improper at both ends. Presumably $0.4$ was convenient.

Comment: So $0.4$ was chosen arbitrarily? Any other number except $1/2$ would suffice?

Comment: @Steven: Yes. I’d choose whatever seemed likely to make the arithmetic easy.

Comment: The principal value over $(\epsilon,1]$ exists, but the integral diverges as $\epsilon \to 0$.

Answer (score 2):

An integral with $f=O(x^{-2})$ from $0$ (or wherever $x^{-2}$ creates a pole) should diverge.

Comment: The integrand is $O(x^{-1})$ as $x \to 0$, but your point still stands.

Comment: You're right, my mistake (I was thinking as $x\to\infty$, as you can probably tell).